# Cleanup after a async function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm migrating a React project to TypeScript but I'm struggling to type out this function and, subsequently the `useEffect`. I know that `registerListener` has to return a `Promise` but how do I access the value of that promise in `useEffect`?

```
const registerListener = async () => {
  const listener = await someAsyncAction();

  return { listener };
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  const { listener } = registerListener();

  return () => {
    removeListener(listener);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: If it returns a promise, await to its result too, but how it's related to typing? You didn't type anything, what have you tried? What are the warnings?

Comment: you cannot call removeListener in useEffect unless it's actually a subscription, or AbortController

Comment: This is how the code looks with JavaScript only. I tried to type out `reggisterListener` as `Promise<{ listener: SomeType }>` but I do not wish to use async useEffect. I can wrap the call to `regiserListener` in a function but I won't be able to access the result of the function to return a cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare a return type on registerListener?

```
const registerListener = async (): Promise<{ listener: someAsyncActionReturnType }> => {
  const listener = await someAsyncAction();

  return { listener };
};
```